# Matrices and linear transformations, find f based on it's matrix in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, linear-transformations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, knowing that it's matrix based on the basis $B=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$ is: $M(f)_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\-1&2&1\\1&3&4\end{pmatrix}$ then find $f(x,y,z).$

First, I really want to understand this, in special, what the matrix of the function based on a basis actually ***is*** and what it does to the function? What's it's importance? also what it's properties? Why does it help us and can we rewrite the function based on that? And why is that matrix important to the question? (finding $f$)

My attempt:

We know that the coordinates of an arbitrary vector $v=(x,y,z)$ based on a basis are (let's name the vectors from $B$ in order $b_1,b_2,b_3$):
$$v=\lambda_1b_1+\lambda_2b_2+\lambda_3b_3$$
Where $\lambda_{1,2,3}$ are the ***actual coordinates***. To calculate the function matrix, I know that we have:

$$f(b_1) = \lambda_{1,1}b_1'+\lambda_{1,2}b_2'+\lambda_{1,3}b_3'$$ 
$$...$$

and so on, where $b_1',b_2',b_3'$ are some other vectors from some other basis from the ***domain***, right? Now... How I know that the matrix I was given is based on the canonic basis if it's not mentioned? Since the matrix of a function must be corelated to 2 basis, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and compute the coordinates of $(x,y,z)$ in the basis $B$. That is, find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$ such that $(x,y,z)=\alpha(1,1,0),\beta(0,1,0)+\gamma(0,1,1)$. Then you will know that\begin{multline}f(x,y,z)=\alpha\bigl((1,1,0)-(0,1,0)+(0,1,1)\bigr)+\\+\beta\bigl((1,1,0)+2(0,1,0)+3(0,1,1)\bigr)+\gamma\bigl(2(1,1,0)+(0,1,0)+4(0,1,1)\bigr),\end{multline}because asserting that $M$ is the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B$ (twice) *mean*s that:

- $f(1,1,0)=(1,1,0)-(0,1,0)+(0,1,1)$;
- $f(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)+2(0,1,0)+3(0,1,1)$;
- $f(0,1,1)=2(1,1,0)+(0,1,0)+4(0,1,1)$.

Comment: Why *will i know that* second line? 
if we apply $f$ on both sides, don't we get: $f(x,y,z) =\alpha f(1,1,0) + \beta f(0,1,0)+\gamma f(0,1,1)?$

Comment: Yes, you will. And I explained right after how to compute $f(1,1,0)$, $f(0,1,0)$, and $f(0,1,1)$.

Comment: but, for example $f(1,1,0)$ should not be: $f(1,1,0)=-(1,1,0)+(0,1,0)+2(0,1,1)?$

Comment: No. Since $(1,1,0)$ is the first vectors of $B$, the coefficients are obtained from the first column of $M$: $1$, $-1$, and $1$.

Comment: Oh so it's on columns

Comment: okay, so you want to find $f(x,y,z)$, can you explain the thought process on why you wanted to compute the coordinates of (x,y,z) in the basis $B$?

Comment: Because all that $M$ tells me are the values of $f$ at the elements of $B$. So, I needed to know how to express $(x,y,z)$ with repect to that basis.

Comment: Okay, and why does the coordinates of $f(x,y,z)$ in basis $B$ gives you the actual function $f$?

Comment: Since $f$ is linear, if I know $f(1,1,0)$, $f(0,1,0)$, and $f(0,1,1)$, then I know$$f\bigl(\alpha(1,1,0)+\beta(0,1,0)+\gamma(0,1,1)\bigr).$$It will be equal to$$\alpha f(1,1,0)+\beta f(0,1,0)+\gamma f(0,1,1).$$

Comment: Yeah, but what you do with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ after that? How you get to $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: I don't get them **after** that. I get them **before** that, solving the system$$(x,y,z)=\alpha(1,1,0)+\beta(0,1,0)+\gamma(0,1,1).$$

Comment: Okay, I see, I got it, but now, the rest of the questions? From the begining? Why do we need this matrix? And why can it be in any arbitrary basis?

Comment: You need that matrix because that's the matrix provided by whoever gave you this problem. And it can be any any arbitrary basis because the matrix of a linear transformation can be defined for any basis.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the expression in terms of the cannonical basis $B_c=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Calculate the matrix $M$ of the change of basis, or equivalently, the matrix of the linear transformation $Id:({\mathbb R}^3,B_c)\to ({\mathbb R}^3,B)$ (that is, the identity map but considering the canonical basis on the beginning and your besis in the end.

Now the matrix of $f$ with respect to the canonical basis will be $$M(f)_{B_c}=M\cdot M(f)_B\cdot M^{-1}$$ and you just have to compute 
$$f(x,y,z)=M(f)_{B_c}\cdot (x,y,z)^t.$$

Comment: How you guessed it was in terms of the cannonical basis? What is the intuition behind that? Also how did you get that $M(f)_{B_c}=M\times M(f)_B\times M^-1$, and what is $M$?

Comment: Usually, when you ask for the "formula", you write it using the canonical basis.

M is defined in my answer, is tha matrix of the change of basis from $B_c$ to $B$, or equivalently, the matrix of the identity trasnformation considering the cannical basis on the start and the basis $B$ on the arrival.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a discussion:

I think all of your firstly asked questions have answers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map). And for if the basis is not mentioned conventionally we take the canonical basis. Here is an [Example](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node44.html).